# SQL/PHP - Select between two dates, with date printed out

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am trying to select between two dates in PHP and SQL. However, my PHP dates are printed like this:

```
July 1, 2017
```

and

```
July 30, 2017
```

The problem is, that in the database I am selecting from, the dates is stored like this
yyyy-MM-DD:
`2017-07-01`
and `2017-07-30`

I am trying to make a query, to select between two dates:

```
SELECT dl.list_id, dl.id, dl.date, dl.list_name, dl.list_supplier, dls.reference, dls.mawb, dls.shipment, dls.kg
FROM driving_lists dl LEFT JOIN
driving_list_shipments dls
ON dl.list_id = dls.list_id
WHERE dl.deleted=0 AND dls.kg > 0 AND dl.date between 'FORMAT(July 01, 2017,'yyyy-MM-DD')' and 'FORMAT(July 30, 2017,'yyyy-MM-DD')'
ORDER BY dl.list_id
```

So, the problem is with this:

```
dl.date between 'FORMAT(July 01, 2017,'yyyy-MM-DD')' and 'FORMAT(July 30, 2017,'yyyy-MM-DD')'
```

How can I select between two dates by converting it to the format, that the database uses?

Comment: try this => UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) ..in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **date()** php function
Like this

```
$date1='July 30, 2017';
$date1=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1));
$date2='July 1, 2017';
$date2=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date2));
```

If you print `$date1` and `$date2` it will look like

```
"2017-07-30"

"2017-07-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `str_to_date()` if you want to do the transformation in the database:

```
WHERE dl.deleted = 0 AND dls.kg > 0 AND
      dl.date between str_to_date('July 01, 2017', '%M %d, %Y') and 
                      str_to_date('July 30, 2017', '%M %d, %Y')
```

Note:  `dl.date` should be stored as a date in the database.